# Forcing a layer repaint

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I have a kiosk application running on Ubuntu server 14.04.3 and **chrome**. Currently I have some code which hides the mouse if there was no movement for 2 seconds and once the user attempts to move the mouse again it shows up again. The trick is by using a `cursor:none` and adding an overlay:

js:

```
var body = $('body');
function hideMouse() {
    body.addClass("hideMouse");

    body.on('mousemove', function(){

        if(window.hiding) return true;
        window.hiding = true;
        body.removeClass("hideMouse");
        $('div.mouseHider').remove();
        clearTimeout(window.hideMouse);
        window.hideMouse = setTimeout(function(){
            body.addClass("hideMouse");
            $('<div class="mouseHider"></div>').css({
                position: 'fixed',
                top: 0,
                left: 0,
                height: '100%',
                width: '100%',
                zIndex: 99999
            }).appendTo(body);
            redraw(document.body);
            setTimeout(function(){
                window.hiding = false;
            }, 100);
        }, 4000);
    });
}

function redraw(e) {
    e.style.display = 'none';
    e.offsetHeight;
    e.style.display = 'block';
}
```

css:

```
body.hideMouse *, body.hideMouse{
    cursor: none;
}
body.hideMouse *{
    pointer-events: none !important;
}
```

This code works perfectly fine but there is only 1 caveat. When the page first loading it attempts to hide the mouse with the same trick but the mouse is still sticking there since it just didn't repainted the layer I guess. If I want it to work, I have to move the mouse a little bit and from then on it will work as expected and hide the mouse. The thing is that the kiosk application is restarting every day which means I boot the X display again and the mouse is being reset to the middle of the screen and it just sticks there until I move it a little bit. I hope you understand what I mean.

Do you guys have any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: You need that when the application load but user does't move the mouse, then cursor should hide after a specified time right?

Comment: Usually when targeting the cursor you want to call it as a selector: `selector { cursor: none; }`

Comment: How do you call `hideMouse()` ?

Comment: @A.J Exactly. In that case the mouse icon just stays there just like the web page isn't aware of the mouse just yet

Comment: @Zealander I forgot to add it here, I'm calling the `hideMouse()` method when the page load. ether, I'm not sure what you are trying to say

Answer (score 0):

You don't need all that code to do what you want. You could do:

1. Create a `setTimeout` to hide the cursor after 2s as soon as the page is loaded
2. When someone moves the mouse, you:

   2.1. Show the cursor again

   2.2. Clear the current `setTimeout`

   2.3. And create the `setTimeout` to hide the cursor after 2s again.

The code below should work for you:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {  
  var cursorNone = document.getElementById('cursor-none');
  
  var t = setTimeout(hideMouse, 2000);

  document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    showMouse();
    clearTimeout(t);
    t = setTimeout(hideMouse, 2000);
  });

  function hideMouse() {
    cursorNone.classList.remove('hidden');
  }

  function showMouse() {
    cursorNone.classList.add('hidden');
  }
});
```

```css
#cursor-none {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
  cursor: none;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="cursor-none" class="hidden"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: I'm not sure why but this just doesn't work. I can still see the mouse. I've double checked and the code should be fine. The overlay div is actually being shown when needed and hidden when needed but the mouse is just ignoring it and being shown.